# Regex - Stop after finding the first pattern

Tags: python-3.x, regex

For a string like this:

```
1. Jane, Doe2. Good, Jay3. Turn, Bob[key]
```

Either `Jane, Doe` needs to be extracted if no `[key]` is present then whatever is between `1.` and `2.`
(or)

`Turn, Bob` if `[key]` is present

Put another way:

1. If `[key]` is present, then the person before `[key]` needs to be extracted and the process stopped.
2. If `[key]` is not present, then pick up whoever is after `1.`

I tried this but it pulls up both Jane, Doe and Turn, Bob

```
(\.([^\.])(.+)\[key\])|(1\.(.+)2\.)
```

How to stop after finding the first successful pattern, knowing that patterns are read left to right? `[key]` can be anyone - `1,2 or 3`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these requirements, you may use this regex in Python with an alternation:

```sh
(?<=\d\.\s)[a-zA-Z, ]+(?=\[key])|(?<=1\.\s)(?!.*\[key])[a-zA-Z, ]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1O5jSa/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=\d\.\s)`: Positive lookbehind to assert that there is a digit followed by dot followed by a whitespace before the current position
- `[a-zA-Z, ]+`: Match 1+ of letter, space or comma characters
- `(?=\[key])`: Positive lookahead to assert that there is a text `[key]` after the current position
- `|`: OR
- `(?<=1\.\s)`: Positive lookbehind to assert that there is a digit `1` followed by dot followed by a whitespace before the current position
- `(?!.*\[key])`: Negative lookbehind to assert that there is no `[key]` text after the current position
- `[a-zA-Z, ]+`: Match 1+ of letter, space or comma characters

Comment: A little twerk: if the name contains a period (like Sr, Doe, John), how to escape that?

Comment: @anubhava, yes I have tested it, this works fine for me, cheers.

Comment: @anubhava sorry should have been more pointed -- for this: 1. Jane, Doe2. Good, Jay3. Sr. Doe, John[key]

Comment: @skrubber: Ok got it. You then then use: `(?<=\d\.\s)[a-zA-Z., ]+(?=\[key])|(?<=1\.\s)(?!.*\[key])[a-zA-Z., ]+` or [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/1O5jSa/5)

Comment: works like a charm. so "[a-zA-Z., ]+" is a word followed by a period; what does the comma do?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z., ]+` means match 1 or more of letters or comma or dot or space

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you put .+ into your regex but it's greedy and matches `. Good, Jay3. Turn, Bob`. so the left part of the alternation matches.

Suggest you remove the .+ on both sides of the alternation ( | ).

Comment: Not sure I got you. How would I capture the string between the period(.) and the [key] then? Isnt (.+) non-greedy against (.*)?